# How to get JFrame's button sizes?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, size

I created a JFrame and in the top right corner I have 3 buttons (minimize, maximize, close).  How do I get the size of these buttons?  I want to place a new button just to the left of the minimize button in the title bar but I need to know how much space these existing buttons take up so that I don't place my button on top of them.   ie If you open a recent version of the Chrome browser you'll see a button beside the minimize button in the browser window.  I want to do the same sort of thing in my Java application.

Comment: *"I want to place a new button just to the left of the minimize button.."*  How about instead - Don't do that?  It would not be the 'path of least surprise' for the user to add non-standard buttons to an otherwise standard frame chrome.  What does your button do?

Comment: The frame decorations are generally supplied by the os. If you do some research, you will find that this is generally the holy grail of Swing developers. If the decorations are provided by the look and feel, yd have to walk through the container hierarchy looking for, hopefully, some kind of button, but then you run into the problem of trying to figure out what kind of layout manager is been used to dipslay. It's one hack after another.

Comment: Chrome does away with all that mess by implementing its own window decorations

Comment: My new button is used to toggle whether the JFrame will appear always on top.

Comment: *"..new button is used to toggle whether the JFrame will appear always on top."*  Perhaps better relegated to a `JMenuItem` or a key binding..

Answer (score 0):

What your describing is very advanced.
An alternative route would be to use:

```
setUndecorated(true);
```

Then create your own window decorations. This way everything matches and you can add all of the button that you want.